# Piecewise answer (solution) from DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

Please forgive me for providing only a small piece of code. I solved the 1-D particle-in-a-box quantum mechanics problem. The code is like this.

```
Block[{ψ,tise,bc,hbar,nc,k,sol,cs,L,$Assumptions=k>0&&hbar>0&&L>0},
 SetAttributes[{hbar,L},Constant];
 tise={D[ψ[x],{x,2}]==-k^2 ψ[x]};
 bc=And[ψ[0]==0,ψ[L]==0];
 nc=Integrate[Conjugate[ψ[x]]ψ[x],{x,0,L}]==1;
 sol=DSolve[And[tise,bc],ψ[x],x]//Simplify
]
```

> {{ψ[x]->[Piecewise]  C[1] Sin[k x]   [FormalN]∈[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]&&((k L==2 [FormalN] π&&[FormalN]>=1)||(π+2 [FormalN] π==k L&&[FormalN]>=0))
>         0 True }}

My problem is, I tried a lot of ways to dig out the above solution for later calculations, for example, to normalize it and get the value of `C[1]`. There was no success. I think it too much to post those failed attempts. But perhaps some of you are so experienced that you can show me some examples of how I can further make use of this result.

BTW, the solution is a bit funny because it simply means `k L == n Pi` for all positive integers (natural numbers), but I cannot get Wolfram language to further simplify the result, either. Moreover, there is not a built-in domain for natural numbers, leaving it quite inconvenient for us to describe some conditions.

=== Follow up ===
To make my question clearer, I do something more in the block I showed earlier:

```
Block[{\[Psi], tise, bc, hbar, nc, k, sol, cs, L, 
  $Assumptions = x \[Element] Reals && x > 0 && k > 0 && hbar > 0 && L > 0},
 SetAttributes[{hbar, L}, Constant];
 tise = {D[\[Psi][x], {x, 2}] == -k^2 \[Psi][x]};
 bc = And[\[Psi][0] == 0, \[Psi][L] == 0];
 nc = Integrate[Conjugate[\[Psi][x]] \[Psi][x], {x, 0, L}] == 1;
 sol = DSolve[And[tise, bc], \[Psi][x], x] // Simplify;
 Solve[((nc /. sol[[1]]) // FullSimplify) /. {C[1] -> x}, {x, k}, 
  Method -> Reduce] // FullSimplify
]
```

and I got

> {{k -> ConditionalExpression[(2 [FormalN] [Pi])/L, [FormalN] [Element] Integers && Sqrt[2/L - x^2] == 0 && 
>        Sqrt[L] x <= Sqrt[2] && [FormalN] >= 1]}, 
>   {k -> ConditionalExpression[([Pi] + 2 [FormalN] [Pi])/L, [FormalN] [Element] Integers && Sqrt[2/L - x^2] == 0 && 
>        Sqrt[L] x <= Sqrt[2] && [FormalN] >= 0]}}

When studying quantum mechanics, at this point we should find the acceptable values of k and find the normalization constant C[1]. The possible k's are hidden in the logical rules above. As to C[1], Wolfram Language simply refuses to provide any useful result, although you can see that it really already knows the answer (`Sqrt[2/L - x^2] == 0`).

Comment: You have put your code in a Block and told it that the variable sol is local to the block. Hence the solution sol is not available outside the Block. Start by removing the scoping of sol.

Comment: Thank you bill but my question is not like that. Even in the block, I have no idea how this solution can help me, say, to get the normalization constant `C[1]`.

Comment: That's not a normalization constant. The solution holds for every value of C[1].

Comment: Yes, you are right, but to complete a quantum mechanics calculation, we need to find a specific value of C[1] that normalize the wavefunction. So as long as we are dealing with a quantum mechanics problem here, C[1] IS the normalization that we have to determine.